# How to determine which TYPO3 Version is used without logging in?

Tags: typo3

I stumbled upon [this website](https://www.t3versions.com/) right here, where I can simply enter a URL and get the exact version of the TYPO3 that's beeing used. How do I determine that without having any login data? Does this work for any TYPO3-Version?

Comment: You should have a look at https://www.t3versions.com/about. I just did a quick check and expected I got "TYPO3 version could not be determined. Certain parts of the TYPO3 website seem to be secured."

Answer (score 2):

There is an [FAQ page](https://www.t3versions.com/faq) with details on how the version is detected. Among other mechanisms, the analyzer compares source files unique to each TYPO3 version:

> How does t3versions determine the TYPO3 major version?
>
> t3versions checks the TYPO3 frontend output, the TYPO3 backend login (if available) and the existence of files (fingerprinting), which are unique for each TYPO3 major version. In order to determine unique files for each TYPO3 major version, the files of all available TYPO3 versions (8+ GB of data excluding PHP files) have been analyzed of for uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

Typo3 current version can be find from here Typo3 source file.

```
typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Information/Typo3Version.php
```

Like

```
protected const VERSION = '11.5.16';
```

Comment: the content of this file should not be visible if you have no BE access (BE login or direct server access like SSH/SFTP/...)